# MySqlDataReader doesn't close after calling Close() on the reader

Tags: mysql, .net, .net-core, mysql-connector, mysqldatareader

I am not quite sure if I am experiencing a bug or I don't get how it supposed to work. So recently I've been trying to resolve this exception `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.'` and I started a debugging session to see what is going on. What I saw doesn't quite compute in my head (see the attached screenshot).

After I call `reader.Close()`, the property `IsClosed` stays false, and repeated calls to `.Close()` (in the immediate windows) do not change that.

Is this expected behavior and my issue is somewhere else, or is this a bug and the cause of the exception?

This happens when using `MySql.Data` v6.10.3-rc (from nuget.org), which is the only one supporting .NET Standard as of now. Also, the code is compiled to a .NET Core 2.0 app.

**UPD**: There are tasks around, but the reader is only worked with from the main thread. Also, `reader` is declared as `DbDataReader`, from which `MySqlDataReader` is inherited.

**UPD2**: Apparently, if I call `((MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader)reader).Close()`, then the reader closes properly. Looks to me like a bug in the connector and how they use virtual methods. Right?

[image: Debugger session]

Comment: are you inside an async task??

Comment: @apomene Nope, outside the task, normal single-threaded code. There are tasks around but they don't deal with the reader, only the data taken from the reader.

Comment: What happens if you call `reader.Dispose()`? Does it get disposed of?

Comment: @waka Nothing happens. However, if I do this: `((MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader)reader).Close()`, then it works. `reader` is declared as `DbDataReader` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you always use all your readers within a `using` clause. I use every reader and connection object within using clauses and have not once noticed any error or not closing. I don't see many ways things could go wrong with the `using` clause.

Comment: There's a bug in MySqlDataReader implementation, they do not override the method so the virtual call resolves to empty implementation of DbDatReader.

Comment: i just noticed you talked about using v6.x since only that is supported on standard. I am currently using 8.0.8-dmr and it works fine. There is a newer version as well if you want to try

Comment: Even after reading the documentation, I still don't get what's the difference between the 6.x and 8.x connectors.

Comment: I had created this nuget called `mysql.simple` and I had been using that one since. https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Simple
It contains wrapper classes which I initially made to handle issues such as this. Right now it got many other helper functions too. You can always pull out the mysqlreader object out of it. 
I it wouldn't be too much work you can try it out. You shouldn't be facing any closing issues with this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing more than just adding in a using statement, since as I just witnessed an exception will still leave a reader open.

While it does add some overhead, unless you can be 100% sure that you will not have an error or some bad data such as a wonderful null exception error, use exception handling.

use a simple try/catch statement and be sure the reader close and declare the reader outside the exception handling so that even on an error the reader is closed.